# Buttons not working according to the code

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-intent

I am trying to make a small app in which I have 4 buttons in the `MainActivity` and each of the buttons are coded to their particular classes, but when I press the first button it reopens the `MainActivity` instead of the particular page and the rest of the buttons are not working.

How to solve this?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Doubles = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Singles = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    total = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    score = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    Doubles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myintent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Doubles.class);

            startActivity(myintent1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is your Registered Event Listener for only Doubles Button.
so in order to do same for other
just use

```
 Singles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //stuff here

        }
    });

total.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //stuff here

        }
    });

score.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //stuff here

        }
    });
```

and While you clicking on Doubles ..Your are navigating to second page named Doubles.class...
check  `setContentView()` method in Doubles.java which u need to change to another layout

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this way use onClick properity

```
//in activity
public void doublesButtonClicked(View v)
{
....
}

//in xml

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button_double"
        android:onClick="doublesButtonClicked"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Button" />
```